# What is the idiomatic translation of the russian phrase "дело ясное что дело темное"?

Tags: idioms

The literal translation is "it is clear that the case is dark", however, this translation does not do any good to the original.

The word "дело" appears twice in the phrase, but it has a different meaning in each case:

1. At the beginning - "дело ясное". Means literally - "the case is clear", i.e. "it is clear" or "it is understood". There is no real "case" here.
2. At the end "что дело темное". Literally - "that the case is dark". Here is the word "дело" really means "case". The word "темное", although it means "dark", in this phrase it serves as an antonym to "ясное" (clear), i.e. a better translation would be "opaque" rather than "dark".

So the Russian phrase plays on the contradiction:

1. "дело ясное" = "clear case"
2. "дело темное" = "opaque case"
3. "дело ясное что дело темное" could be literally seen as "clear case" = "opaque case"

Of course, like I said the word "дело" does not really mean "case" in the first part. So it is a word play - the literal meaning does not make sense because how come "clear case" = "opaque case"? It is nonsense. Yet, the phrase has the meaning that it is clear that the situation is unclear.

There must be a similar word play in English to denote the same thing. I am curious - what would it be?

Comment: An old expression: *As clear as mud*.

Comment: That should do it! Could you arrage your comment as an answer so I could credit you?

Comment: I leave the answer to others. God bless.

Comment: 'They say it's not as straightforward as they say it is.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As clear as mud](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20clear%20as%20mud):

informal
: very difficult to understand : not clear at all

Comment: While this may be a serviceable translation for most ends and purposes, I am somewhat puzzled by the OP's acceptance of the answer. Reading the question, I was under an impression that what is sought is something that at the same time conveys the unclarity of whatever is under discussion **and** the **meta-clarity** about that unclarity. 'Clear as mud' does not convey the meta-clarity.

Comment: @jsw29 - You are making a subtle point here. If there is a better idiom I can mark it as the answer instead. For now there is not much to chose from.